Limits coming from Lagrange Inversion Theorem
$y=e^x\implies x=\ln y=\ln(1+(y-1))\implies$
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(y-1)^n\tag1$$
On the other hand, by
Lagrange inversion theorem,
with $y=f(x)=e^x$, $a=0$, we have
$$x=g(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n\frac{(y-1)^n}{n!}\tag2$$
where
$$g_n=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)^n\right]^{(n-1)}\tag3$$
and $(n-1)$ stands for derivative $n-1$ times.
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, we deduce that $g_n=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!$
If we didnt know the inverse function of the function $e^x$, how could it be possible to evaluate the limit in $(3)?$ I think Lagrange inversion theorem is not useful. Even in simple examples, we need to evaluate very complicated limits. What do you think?
Thanks.

Updated comment: the derivatives are $B^{(n)}_{n-1}=S^{(1)}_n$ with Norlund B and this Stirling numbers of the first kind formula
